# Scala - reformatting hash-map

Tags: scala, hashmap

I have some Python code that processes a fairly complex hashmap (Example Input), restructures it and creates (Example Output) a simplified version of it. I'm looking for the best way to tackle this with Scala, i.e. built in or external libs? I'm new to Scala and just getting to grips with it, so some guidance here would be really helpful.

This was fairly easy to do using Python and I'm hoping that will be the with Scala.

Input:

```
data_in = {
    'map': {
        'stats': {
            'uphosts': u'3',
            'timestr': u'Thu Mar 20 18:18:09 2014',
            'downhosts': u'0',
            'totalhosts': u'3',
            'elapsed': u'1.71'
        },
        'scaninfo': {
            u'tcp': {
                'services': u'80,443',
                'method': u'syn'
            }
        },
        'command_line': u'command goes here'
    },
    'scan': {
        u'2a00:2384:0:208f::15': {
            'status': {
                'state': u'up',
                'reason': u'nd-response'
            },
            'hostname': u'static.xyz.com',
            'vendor': {
                u'00:0C:67:99:6f:96': u'VMware'
            },
            'addresses': {
                u'mac': u'00:gf:29:99:6D:96',
                u'ipv6': u'a848:2384:0:3456::15'
            },
            u'tcp': {
                80: {
                    'product': '',
                    'state': u'open',
                    'version': '',
                    'name': u'http',
                    'conf': u'3',
                    'extrainfo': '',
                    'reason': u'syn-ack',
                    'cpe': ''
                },
                443: {
                    'product': '',
                    'state': u'open',
                    'version': '',
                    'name': u'https',
                    'conf': u'3',
                    'script': {
                        u'ssl-cert': u'place holder'
                    },
                    'extrainfo': '',
                    'reason': u'syn-ack',
                    'cpe': ''
                }
            }
        },
        u'2a00:2384:0:208f::16': {
            'status': {
                'state': u'up',
                'reason': u'nd-response'
            },
            'hostname': u'static.edf.com',
            'vendor': {
                u'00:0C:55:AE:33:ff': u'VMware'
            },
            'addresses': {
                u'mac': u'00:54:29:fg:55:0F',
                u'ipv6': u'8938:8584:0:8685::16'
            },
            u'tcp': {
                80: {
                    'product': '',
                    'state': u'open',
                    'version': '',
                    'name': u'http',
                    'conf': u'3',
                    'extrainfo': '',
                    'reason': u'syn-ack',
                    'cpe': ''
                },
                443: {
                    'product': '',
                    'state': u'open',
                    'version': '',
                    'name': u'https',
                    'conf': u'3',
                    'script': {
                        u'ssl-cert': u'place holder'
                    },
                    'extrainfo': '',
                    'reason': u'syn-ack',
                    'cpe': ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Required output:

```
data_out_1 = [
    {'address': u'2a00:2384:0:208f::15',
  'hostname': u'static.xyz.com',
  'ports': {80: {'reason': u'syn-ack', 'state': u'open'},
            443: {'reason': u'syn-ack',
                  'ssl_cert': u'place holder',
                  'state': u'open'}}},
    {'address': u'2a00:2384:0:208f::16',
  'hostname': u'static.edf.com',
  'ports': {80: {'reason': u'syn-ack', 'state': u'open'},
            443: {'reason': u'syn-ack',
                  'ssl_cert': u'place holder',
                  'state': u'open'}}}]
```

Answer (score 8):

That isn't typesafe.

Hashmaps can't store different types of data*. Start by creating datastructures to hold the input data ([case classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) will help here).

So your stats object might look like

```
case class Stats(uphosts: Int, timeStr: Datetime, downhosts: Int, totalHosts: Int, elapsed:Double)
```

- ignoring subtyping here for the moment.

Comment: Definitely +1. Get in the habit of producing domain abstractions for everything you deal with. Dictionaries are hideous for structuring data (unless it's a dictionary, of course…).

Comment: It's worth noting that this advice isn't scala-specific.  Giant, insane dictionaries are are a terrible idea no matter what language you're working in... *including* python.